# How to resolve the import org.obix?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Obix with Java, so I found a very simple tutorial in Google. I have all libraries like: obix.jar, dom.jar, jaxen-full.jar, sax.jar, saxpath.jar, and xercesImpl.jar.

The sample.config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration SYSTEM "http://obix-framework.sourceforge.net/docs/obix-configuration.dtd">
<configuration>
  <entry entryKey="message">
    <value>Hello World!</value>
  </entry>
</configuration>
```

And the Java code is:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import org.obix.configuration.Configuration;
import org.obix.configuration.ConfigurationAdapter;
import org.obix.configuration.ConfigurationAdapterFactory;

public final class ObixSample {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ConfigurationAdapterFactory factory = ConfigurationAdapterFactory.newAdapterFactory();

    final Configuration config = Configuration.getConfiguration();
    final ConfigurationAdapter adapter = factory.create(null);
    adapter.adaptConfiguration(config, "sample.config");
    out.println(config.getStringValue("message"));
  }
}
```

So in Eclipse the first three lines for import are red and it says

> The import org.obix cannot be resolved

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You've added the libraries to your build path, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You must have all related JARs in Java Build Path.

```
Right click Project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java build Path > Add JARs in Libraries tab
```

Comment: Can you provide link to tutorial and also for JAR download